# How could I make a function thar goes trough a vector and recognizes the signs of the numbers on it?

Tags: r, vector

I was wondering if someone can help me with this, I need a function that goes trough a vector and recognizes the signs of the numbers inside, thats de basic idea, then I'll try to make some modifications so the function counts every number and shows something like "There are 2 positive numbers and 3 negatives"

Comment: It'd be helpful if you had an example string  or something ... Also: do positive numbers have a `+`sign`?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. There's the `sign()` function that can tell you the sign for a number. Or you could do something like `sum(x>0)` and `sum(x<0)`

Comment: Or `table(x>0)`

Comment: Something like: `x <- c(1,-2,3,-4,5,1,2,3,-7,1,-3,-8,10,-2)
sum(x > 0)
sum(x < 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the following approach (I added also functionality for zeros, remove this feature if it is not needed, or merge it with one of the other two conditions):

```
sign_function <- function(x){
  count_pos_numbers = sum(x>0)
  count_neg_numbers = sum(x<0)
  count_zeros = sum(x==0)
  sprintf("There are %d positive numbers, %d negative numbers, and %d zeros.", count_pos_numbers, count_neg_numbers , count_zeros)
}
```

I hope that I understood your question correctly.

Comment: That was exactly what i wanted, thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome, can you upvote and accept my answer in this case?